# How to insert a snippet with UltiSnips?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-ultisnips, snippets, plugin-supertab

I am using the setup I found in this answer: [UltiSnips and YouCompleteMe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253548/2241241)

namely:

```
" if you use Vundle, load plugins:
Bundle 'ervandew/supertab'
Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Bundle 'SirVer/ultisnips'

" make YCM compatible with UltiSnips (using supertab)
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<C-n>', '<Down>']
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<C-p>', '<Up>']
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = '<C-n>'

" better key bindings for UltiSnipsExpandTrigger
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = "<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = "<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = "<s-tab>"
```

I am working on a `tex` document, and trying to insert the snippet in the screenshot. Pressing tab, or ctrl-n will cycle me through the options presented, but I can't for the life of me insert the snippet. Pressing enter, space of just continuing with { just behaves as if I were typing (which I guess is what is to be expected, but I had no better idea).

What do I need to do to insert the snippet shown there?

[image]

Comment: What about changing forward trigger and backward trigger to `<c-j>` and `<c-k>`? I am using deoplete and have no problem in inserting snippets.

Comment: Use other expansion trigger

Comment: Does `<C-Y>` work if you have the snippet highlighted?

Comment: @jdhao changing the above to `let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = "<c-j>"` doesn't do anything, I press ctrl-j and nothing happens.

Comment: @filbranden Unfortunately, no.

Comment: The forward and backwards triggers are for snippets with multiple fields. Not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<c-g>'
    "strange that I have to change this
    let g:SuperTabMappingForward = '<s-tab>'
    let g:SuperTabMappingBackward = '<tab>'
```

go to the snip option in the menu, and press `ctrl-g`.

Originally, it supposed to be tab, what expands. But supertab has taken control over tab.

Comment: This doesn't work either. I think I will need to disable all other plugins and figure out what is going on ...

Comment: You can check my vimrc. I have a similar configuration https://github.com/eyalk5/.vim

Comment: I copied the relevant part